# Login page redirection base on radio button selection after submit in php

Tags: php

I am having two different types of users to login. I am using radio buttons for users and below that username and password.Based on the radiobutton selection the page should redirect if the username and password are correct

0) {?>

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var form = $('form[name="form1"]'),
    radio = $('input[name="RadioGroup1"]'),
    choice = '';

radio.change(function(e) {
    choice = this.value;

    if (choice === 'yes') {
        form.attr('action', 'rmain.php');
        <?php session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        session_write_close();
        header("location: rmain.php");
        exit();?>
    } else {
        form.attr('action', 'home.php');
        <?php session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        session_write_close();
        header("location: home.php");
        exit();?>
    }
});
```

});

```
<?php   }
    else {

        $errmsg_arr[] = 'user name and password not found';
        $errflag = true;
        if($errflag) {
            $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
            session_write_close();
            header("location: login.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
}
else {
    die("Query failed");
}
```

?>

Comment: Can you share the code that you have tried?

Comment: What did you try yet??

Comment: Can we see what you got so far?